# Using Custom Keyboard in iOS app

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

Can I use custom keyboard in all my app by creating a single custom keyboard as a static library?

Eg: I want to create a custom keyboard and use it in my app A, B and C. How do I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the iOS8 custom keyboards API:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html